# What is the name of the class of topological spaces with the following property ....?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, selection-principles

What is the name of the class of topological spaces with the following property $P$ ?

$X\in P$ iff for any open set $W$ in $X$ and any point $x\in \overline{W}\setminus W$ there is an open set $V$ such that $V\subseteq W$ and $\overline{V}\cap (\overline{W}\setminus W)=\{x\}$.

Any $k$-Frechet-Urysohn  regular space $X$ with countable pseudocharacter has the property $P$. Hence, any regular first-countable space $X$ has the property $P$.

This property $P$ is close to  the Whyburn property.